# Fundamental group and cellular space

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Suppose that $\pi_{1}\left(Y, y_{0}\right)$ is finitely presented. How can we construct a path connected finite cellular space $\left(X, x_{0}\right)$ and a continuous map $\psi:\left(X, x_{0}\right) \rightarrow\left(Y, y_{0}\right)$ such that the induced homomorphism
$$
\pi_{1}(\psi): \pi_{1}\left(X, x_{0}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}\left(Y, y_{0}\right)
$$
is an isomorphism.

I think we have to use this theorem, but the construction part is not clear to me: If $f:\left(X, x_{0}\right) \rightarrow\left(Y, y_{0}\right)$ is a homotopy equivalence of spaces with base points, then $f_{*}: \pi_{1}\left(X, x_{0}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}\left(Y, y_{0}\right)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Notation question: Are you deliberately using lowercase `o` and numeral `0` interchangeably in subscripts, or are those typos? Is $y_o$ meant to be the more standard $y_0$?

Comment: yes I mean y_{0}. I will correct it.

Comment: Choose a presentation $\pi_1Y=\langle \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\mid R_1,\dots,R_k\rangle$. Represent the generators by maps $\alpha_i:S^1\rightarrow Y$ and obtain $\bigvee^n_{i=1} S^1\rightarrow Y$ which induces an epimorphism on $\pi_1$. Each relation is a word in the $\alpha_i$, and so corresponds in an obvious way to a map $R_i:S^1\rightarrow\bigvee^n_{i=1} S^1$. For each relation attach a 2-cell to $\bigvee^n_{i=1} S^1$ by the map $R_i$. Call $X$ the resulting 2-complex. There is an induced map $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Use the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem to find $\pi_1X$ and show $f_*$ is an iso.